# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column

Tags: sql, mysql-error-1054

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT efforts.user_id, project_tasks.task_name, sum(hours) 
FROM efforts, users, project_tasks
INNER JOIN PROJECT_TASKS pu ON efforts.project_task_id = pu.id  
INNER JOIN USERS u ON efforts.users_id = u.id
WHERE project_tasks.project_id = '2';
```

And when I run it I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'efforts.project_task_id' in 'on clause'
```

Why am I getting this error?

[image]

Project_task_id belongs to efforts table

[Image of my efforts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTggZ.jpg)

Updated:

```
SELECT u.full_name, pu.task_name, hours 
FROM efforts
INNER JOIN project_tasks pu ON efforts.project_task_id = pu.id   
INNER JOIN users u ON efforts.user_id = u.id 
GROUP BY user_id, task_name
```

Comment: did u have this column in efforts table ?

Comment: Please provide the table description for the efforts table..

Comment: I have added the image below to show my table

Comment: does my version of the query work?

Comment: I have edited my post with a link to my efforts table

Comment: Your query didn't work, I got this error `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'project_tasks.task_name' in 'field list'`

Comment: This appears to be a bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60650

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, it should be:

```
SELECT efforts.user_id, pu.task_name, sum(hours)  
FROM efforts
INNER JOIN PROJECT_TASKS pu ON efforts.project_task_id = pu.id   
INNER JOIN USERS u ON efforts.user_id = u.id 
WHERE pu.project_id = '2';
```

Comment: The last line should be:  WHERE pu.project_id = '2';

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck I tried this and it didn't work I got this error `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'project_tasks.task_name' in 'field list'`

Comment: Thanks, Okay I tried this and now it thrown up this error `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'efforts.users_id' in 'on clause'`.

Comment: I tried this and it worked thank you. I extended the query so that it looks like the following. I've updated my post

Answer (score 2):

Note that as far as I know, MySQL is case-sensitive on table names (not on column names)... That might cause some trouble in your query...? Along with StevieG's correction

Comment: Your suggestion actually worked and solved my bug on which I'm struggling.