# Error Code 1054 unknown column on cross join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables `item`, `store` and `stock_movement`. The stock movement has the fields `id`, `item_id`, `store_id` and `quantity`. I would like to create a view showing the sum of the quantities of each item in each store. If there is no `stock_movement` entry for an item in a store, the quantity should be zero.

I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT item.*, store.id, SUM(s.quantity) AS quantity
FROM item, store 
LEFT JOIN stock_movement s ON s.item_id = item.id AND store.id = s.store_id
GROUP BY store.id, item.id;
```

I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'item.id' in 'on clause'

If I switch the query to use `FROM store, item` the unknown column changes:

> Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'store.id' in 'on clause'

[This answer to use `INNER JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7333229/428543) won't work for me since there are some items and stores without corresponding `stock_movement` entries i.e the result is missing a few rows.

So is there a way to do this cross join?

Comment: You are already mixing implicit inner joins and an explicit left join by using the comma-separated table list in the `FROM` clause. Probably all you need is a `LEFT JOIN` between `stock_movement` and `store`, but can you post a small sample of rows from each table, together with a sample of what you expect the query output to be?

Comment: Have you tried aliasing the item and store tables?

Comment: @Zoldren yes. Same error.

Comment: The error is because of the use of both the implicit join and the explicit join, using a table from the implicit join in the explicit one's `ON` clause.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski using an explicit join worked. Please add an answer describing this further. Specifically implicit vs explicit cross joins as I can't seem to find a proper explanation online

Comment: @topher [this question addresses it thoroughly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins). Listing tables separated by commas in the `FROM` clause creates an `INNER JOIN`, but is an older syntax which is no longer preferred. The two are exactly equivalent.  Does sgeddes' answer below give you the expected result already? I would expect that using the explicit join would produce a wildly different result than the `CROSS JOIN` below.

Comment: Actually both implicit and explicit produced the same results without the join to stock_movement. The implicit broke on adding the left join.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski -- That is mistaken -- it isn't equivalent to an `inner join` without `where` criteria (to perform the `on`).  Using commas without `where` criteria is the same as a `cross  join` (cartesian product).

Comment: @sgeddes certainly. I didn't add that part because prior to your answer being accepted I wasn't certain that a cross join was what's actually needed in this instance.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski -- makes sense, just wanted to clarify.  And I too wasn't 100% sure what the desired results were without sample data/desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly define your `cross join`:

```
select i.id, s.id, coalesce(sum(si.quantity),0) quantity
from store s 
  cross join item i 
  left join storeitem si on s.id = si.storeid and i.id = si.itemid
group by i.id, s.id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8a4b/2)

BTW -- by doing it this way, you are creating a cartesian product -- all stores have all items.

Comment: Perfect. No idea why the implicit is failing though.